# Stripe connect with Auth and Capture retrieving Charge in Php

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am implementing Stripe Connect with auth and Capture and so far I am succeeded in it but when I am trying to Capture the authenticated amount I am not able to do so. because stripe does not allow us to pass multiple parameters to **Stripe:: Retrieve** function but its working on curl request which I have developed. which as follow.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges/ch_1CfTe5Dye6RVcYtHp*****/capture \

-u sk_test_C5uYX8juNRT9kTj******: \
-d application_fee=1000 \
-H "Stripe-Account: acct_1CNbqaDy*****" \
-X POST
```

this is working fine but when I try to do the same thing it is giving me an error on an unknown parameter which I can understand bcoz **Stripe:: Retrieve** does not accept extra parameter I am trying to do it in PHP like this

```
$stripe = array(
             "secret_key" => "sk_test_C5uYX8juNRT9k********",
             "publishable_key" => "pk_test_b2gp9tSHK9iP******"
          );

$keystripe = \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
$res = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve(array(
                               "id" =>"ch_1CfTe5Dye6RVcYtHp********",
                               "application_fee" => 1000),
                              array("stripe_account" =>  "acct_1CNbqaDy*****"));

$re = $res->capture();
```

Can someone suggest me how can I archive this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution which is like this.

```
$keystripe = \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_C5uYX8juNRT9kTj9wj******');
$res = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve('ch_1CjkyXDye6RVcYt******', ["stripe_account" => "acct_xxx"]);
$re =  $res->capture(["application_fee" =>1000]);
```

by using this I have resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#capture_charge) on this, you should pass the arguments for capturing to the `capture` function, not the `retrieve` function. It's a two step process, you get the charge object by calling `retrieve`, and then capture it, passing arguments. The code would look like this :

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve("ch_xxx", array("stripe_account" =>  "acct_xxx"));
$charge->capture(array(
  "application_fee" => 1000
),array("stripe_account" =>  "acct_xxx"));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out but I found a solution I am answering it below.

Comment: Cool, but I think we have the exact same answer :)